# GWT Overlay deep copy

Tags: gwt, overlay, clone

What is the best way to make a deep copy of a gwt overlay type?

I'm looking for a function or library that inspects a GWT overlay and clones it. It must be able to clone contained arrays or objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Lineman78's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730463/gwt-overlay-deep-copy/4730645#4730645) and taking into consideration this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript/728694#728694) from A. Levy I created the following function:

```
public class JsoUtils {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends JavaScriptObject> T deepCopy(T obj)
    {
        return (T) deepCopyImpl(obj);
    }

    private static native JavaScriptObject deepCopyImpl(JavaScriptObject obj) /*-{

        if (obj == null) return obj;

        var copy;        

        if (obj instanceof Date) {
            // Handle Date
            copy = new Date();
            copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
        } else if (obj instanceof Array) {
             // Handle Array
            copy = [];
            for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (obj[i] == null || typeof obj[i] != "object") copy[i] = obj[i];
                else copy[i] = @com.amindea.noah.client.utils.JsoUtils::deepCopyImpl(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;)(obj[i]);
            }
        } else {
            // Handle Object
            copy = {};
            for (var attr in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
                    if (obj[attr] == null || typeof obj[attr] != "object") copy[attr] = obj[attr];
                    else copy[attr] = @com.amindea.noah.client.utils.JsoUtils::deepCopyImpl(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;)(obj[attr]);
                }
            }
        }        
        return copy;
    }-*/;

}
```

It supports deep copy of Object, Array, Date, String, Number, or Boolean. As explained by [A. Levy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript/728694#728694) the function will work as long as the data in the objects and arrays form a tree structure.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways that I would consider.  Most of the time overlay objects are used in conjunction with JSON, so you could just stringify the object and parse the results:

```
public native MyOverlayType deepCopy()/*-{
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
}-*/;
```

OR

```
public static native MyOverlayType fromJson(String json)/*-{
      return JSON.parse(json);
}-*/;
public native String getJson()/*-{
      return JSON.stringify(this);
}-*/;
public MyOverlayType deepCopy(){
      return fromJson(getJson());
}
```

The other option is a pure javascript approach which will maintain other stuff such as function pointers and probably be more efficient.

```
public class JsoUtils
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends JavaScriptObject> T deepCopy(T obj)
    {
        return (T) deepCopyImpl(obj);
    }

    private static native JavaScriptObject deepCopyImpl(JavaScriptObject obj)/*-{
        if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null) {
            return obj;
        }

        var c = obj instanceof Array ? [] : {};

        for (var i in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                if (typeof obj[i] !== 'object' || obj[i] === null)
                    c[i] = obj[i];
                else
                    c[i] = @com.example.gwt.client.JsoUtils::deepCopyImpl(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;)(obj[i]);
            }
        }

        return c;
    }-*/;
}
```

Comment: Where do you define clone_obj function? The use of recursiveness with JSNI is one of the things I find more difficult.

Comment: Aw, sorry didn't catch that on my copy... just a sec will update

Comment: +1 Thanks, your function was of great help. I modified it to eliminate the unnecesary type checking, support copying Dates and iterate the arrays in a non-associative way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest way to clone a JavaScriptObject is using the JsonUtils class provided by GWT:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JsonUtils;

final String taskJson = JsonUtils.stringify(selectedTask);
TaskJso task = JsonUtils.safeEval(taskJson).cast();
```